# Strange crash when bringing up a window on Sandboxed cocoa app only on OSX 10.8.3

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, sandbox, crash-reports, ccl

This one is quite weird.  I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion on my dev machine and now every time I bring up the main project window of my app it crashes.  The strange thing is that it only happens on 10.8.3 and it only happen if I sandbox the app.  I have another test machine running 10.8.2 (also Mountain Lion) and the crash does not happen.  Also, if I recreate the app without sandboxing it does not crash. This app is actually created with an implementation of common lisp the uses a cocoa bridge called CCL.

Here are some of the reports I get in the console when my app crashes:

```
4/19/13 11:30:15.605 AM AgentCubes[56676]: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _getWindowRegion: Invalid window
4/19/13 11:30:15.606 AM AgentCubes[56676]: CGSSetWindowLevel: Invalid window 0x137c
4/19/13 11:30:15.607 AM AgentCubes[56676]: PSsetwindowlevel, error setting window level (1000)
4/19/13 11:30:15.607 AM AgentCubes[56676]: CGSClearWindowTags: Invalid window 0x137c
4/19/13 11:30:15.607 AM AgentCubes[56676]: CGSSetIgnoresCycle: error 1000 setting or clearing window tags
4/19/13 11:30:15.623 AM AgentCubes[56676]: *** Assertion failure in -[NativeScrollView scrollerImpPair:updateScrollerStyleForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1187.37/AppKit.subproj/NSScrollView.m:5402
4/19/13 11:30:15.623 AM AgentCubes[56676]: An uncaught exception was raised
4/19/13 11:30:15.624 AM AgentCubes[56676]: Invalid parameter not satisfying: scrollerImpPair == SCROLLER_IMP_PAIR
```

and the big trace:

```
4/19/13 11:30:15.626 AM AgentCubes[56676]: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x99cbee9b __raiseError + 219
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x90a6552e objc_exception_throw + 230
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x99c1e6a8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x93dfb814 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   AppKit                              0x977cd7ab -[NSScrollView(NSPrivate) scrollerImpPair:updateScrollerStyleForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 150
    5   AppKit                              0x977cd6a5 +[NSScrollerImpPair _updateAllScrollerImpPairsForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 406
    6   AppKit                              0x977cd4ff +[NSScrollerImpPair _scrollerStyleRecommendationChanged:] + 159
    7   Foundation                          0x93e52152 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 49
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x99c80861 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 257
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x99bcbe9a _CFXNotificationPost + 2794
    10  Foundation                          0x93e3ac88 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
    11  AppKit                              0x977cd3f5 -[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender setRecommendedScrollerStyleAndNotify:] + 248
    12  AppKit                              0x977cd2e3 __75-[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender scrollerStyleRecommendationUpdateTimerFired:]_block_invoke_0 + 43
    13  AppKit                              0x97eff42f __block_global_0 + 32
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f10f8f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f0cc82 _dispatch_client_callout + 46
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f122e3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 223
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x99bbac39 __CFRunLoopRun + 1961
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x99bba02a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x99bb9e9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  HIToolbox                           0x91e16f5a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242
    21  HIToolbox                           0x91e16cc9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374
    22  HIToolbox                           0x91e16b44 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
    23  AppKit                              0x976e99aa _DPSNextEvent + 724
    24  AppKit                              0x976e91dc -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
    25  AppKit                              0x976df63c -[NSApplication run] + 855
    26  AgentCubes                          0x0001991d ffcall_return + 0
    27  ???                                 0x003cbf9c 0x0 + 3981212
    28  ???                                 0x003cbf9c 0x0 + 3981212
    29  AgentCubes                          0x00019f79 func_start + 94
    30  AgentCubes                          0x0001c52e main + 1310
    31  AgentCubes                          0x00033fb4 _start + 207
    32  AgentCubes                          0x00033ee4 start + 40
)
```

and finally:

```
4/19/13 11:30:15.627 AM AgentCubes[56676]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: scrollerImpPair == SCROLLER_IMP_PAIR'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x99cbee9b __raiseError + 219
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x90a6552e objc_exception_throw + 230
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x99c1e6a8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x93dfb814 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   AppKit                              0x977cd7ab -[NSScrollView(NSPrivate) scrollerImpPair:updateScrollerStyleForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 150
    5   AppKit                              0x977cd6a5 +[NSScrollerImpPair _updateAllScrollerImpPairsForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 406
    6   AppKit                              0x977cd4ff +[NSScrollerImpPair _scrollerStyleRecommendationChanged:] + 159
    7   Foundation                          0x93e52152 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 49
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x99c80861 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 257
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x99bcbe9a _CFXNotificationPost + 2794
    10  Foundation                          0x93e3ac88 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
    11  AppKit                              0x977cd3f5 -[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender setRecommendedScrollerStyleAndNotify:] + 248
    12  AppKit                              0x977cd2e3 __75-[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender scrollerStyleRecommendationUpdateTimerFired:]_block_invoke_0 + 43
    13  AppKit                              0x97eff42f __block_global_0 + 32
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f10f8f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f0cc82 _dispatch_client_callout + 46
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x98f122e3 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 223
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x99bbac39 __CFRunLoopRun + 1961
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x99bba02a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 378
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x99bb9e9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  HIToolbox                           0x91e16f5a RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 242
    21  HIToolbox                           0x91e16cc9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 374
    22  HIToolbox                           0x91e16b44 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
    23  AppKit                              0x976e99aa _DPSNextEvent + 724
    24  AppKit                              0x976e91dc -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
    25  AppKit                              0x976df63c -[NSApplication run] + 855
    26  AgentCubes                          0x0001991d ffcall_return + 0
    27  ???                                 0x003cbf9c 0x0 + 3981212
    28  ???                                 0x003cbf9c 0x0 + 3981212
    29  AgentCubes                          0x00019f79 func_start + 94
    30  AgentCubes                          0x0001c52e main + 1310
    31  AgentCubes                          0x00033fb4 _start + 207
    32  AgentCubes                          0x00033ee4 start + 40
)
```

I am very confused by all this and I am wondering what could have changed in 10.8.3 that interacts badly with the sandboxing?

Comment: I get a similar exception under Lion in a non-sandboxed app, but only if the "Show scroll bars" system preference is set to "Automatically based on input device".  Does that preference affect you too?